# PEAR in WAMP 2 on Windows 7

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, pear, wamp

previously i was using Wamp 1 and Windows XP, but now i have WAMP 2 and Windows 7. unfortunately i dont know how to install PEAR for this...
I dont have directory PEAR in **C:/wamp/**. Why? What i must make?
All guides what i found direct me in C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.4/pear, but i dont have this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php\php5.x.y\`. Run `go-pear.bat` that's in there (I think you might need to adjust a path in this file)

Comment: @Tomy Racks: Is this the PHP versoin that came with WampServer, or did you install another version?

Comment: i downloaded these version: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.1/WampServer2.1d-x64.exe/download which should I choose?

Comment: Hmmm... I've never used these 64b packages. You could try downloading a `5.3.0` addon from here: http://www.wampserver.com/en/addons_php.php, and then copy `/PEAR` folder and `go-pear.bat` file to your `php5.3.4`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Pyrus OF PEAR2: http://pear2.php.net/

Comment: i must use "php pyrus.phar mypear ~/src/my-project/pear" but i dont have these folder

Comment: Well, your php executable should be somewhere in your wamp folder, pyrus.phar is downloadable on the pear2 site and `~/src/my-project/pear` can be any folder you like (pear will be installed there) and on windows will of course be a windows path.